# WP_Query doesn't get sticky post at the top, when used in a page template

Tags: wp-query, loop, page-template, blog, sticky-post

I'm creating a theme in which I've created a page template called page_default-blog.php to be used for creating a blog page. In this file I have the following code:

```
$paged = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
$args = array(
  'paged' => $paged,
);
$custom_query = new WP_Query($args);

if ($custom_query->have_posts()) : 
  while($custom_query->have_posts()) : $custom_query->the_post(); ?>
    the_title();
    echo "<br>";
  endwhile;
endif;
wp_reset_postdata();
```

The problem is that the sticky post doesn't come up at the top, even though the ignore_sticky_posts is set to false by default in $args.

The sticky post is showing at the top if I use the 'index.php' but it's not coming if I set the front page as the blog page.

Please let me know how I can get this to work.
Thanks.

**Edit 1:**
Following is the result of  `var_dump ($custom_query->request);` :

```
string(217) "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private')  ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 4"
```

**Edit 2:**
This is what my template file `page_default-blog.php` looks like:

```
<?php
/*
    Template Name: Blog Default
*/
get_header();

wp_reset_postdata();
wp_reset_query();

$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'ignore_sticky_posts' => 0,
);
$custom_query = new WP_Query( $args );
var_dump( $custom_query->is_home ); // This is returning bool(false)
?>

<div class="container">
  <?php
  if ($custom_query->have_posts()) : while($custom_query->have_posts()) : $custom_query->the_post(); ?>
    <?php
    echo the_title();
    echo "<br>";
    ?>
    <?php endwhile;
  endif;
    wp_reset_postdata();
  ?>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

The above is the exact file that I'm using right now. I simplified it to try to find the problem, but still haven't been able to, as the title for the sticky post is not appearing at the top of the list.

Comment: Where is ignore_sticky_posts set to false in the above $args ?

Comment: the defaults, if any, would be for a page, not an index list; try directly setting the sticky post parameters in your query.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that it is by default set to false and you only set it to true if you don't want the sticky post to show. Also, I tried by setting that to false in the $args array, but still it's not working.

Comment: Add the results of ` var_dump ($custom_query->request);` to the question please.

Comment: @s_ha_dum I've updated the question with the result. Thanks.

Comment: I suspect that something is breaking your page and your queries. Try `wp_reset_query()` and `wp_reset_postdata()` before your query and check what the result is. If this works, then you have a bad query somewhere on the page or from a widget or custom function. To exclude the possibility of a `posts_*` filter or `pre_get_posts` altering your query, try swithing to `get_posts` or add `'suppress_filters' => true` to your query arguments in `WP_Query`

Comment: @PieterGoosen I tried everything that you said, and still it has not worked. I'm starting to think that this may actually be the expected outcome of using WP_Query() in a custom page template. May be I need to use multiple queries to get what I want, as I've spend my entire day on this and I really can't understand why it is acting like this.


Please let me know if you are sure that this is not the expected result. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I cannot get my queries to fail as yours, and I have tested this on a normal page template used as a page and as a static front page. The last thing I can ask to test is `var_dump( $custom_query->is_home )`. This must return `bool(true)`. If this works, then I don't know what else to tell you. It might then be a good idea to run two queries, but still, it does not really solve the bigger issue

Comment: @PieterGoosen The var_dump() is returning bool(false). Please see the `Edit 2` in my question where I've shown the entire template file and thank you for taking the time to help me with this, much appreciated.

Comment: There is a custom filter or something in a plugin or your theme that is messing with `WP_Query`. `is_home` returns true by default in `WP_Query`, and this is what activates the sticky posts. Deactivate your plugins one by one and check what happens. Also, test this on a bundled theme

Comment: @PieterGoosen Holy wow it worked! I was only using the Unyson Framework and deactivating it solved the problem and now the sticky post is coming at top with the var_dump value coming as bool(true). I'm going to open an issue on their github page, but is there a way I can somehow remove their custom filter, `'suppress_filters' => true` didn't work though. But thank you so much for all your help, please add your solution as an answer so I can accept it as the correct one.

Comment: If `suppress_filters` doesn't work, then there isn't to much you can do. You can look for the specific filter and then try to remove it before you run your query arguments. I suspect that your best option would be is to modify the affected code and then hope it will be fixed in the following update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have custom filter in a plugin or in your theme that is messing with `WP_Query`. Your issue is that something is setting `is_home` to `false`. This is not default behavior, by default, `is_home` should return `true` in any custom instance of `WP_Query`.

`is_home` is one of the contributing factors which is responsible for setting up sticky posts at the top in a query, and if its value is `false`, you will not get sticky posts moved to the front.

You should deactivate your plugins one by one and check which one is causing the issue. You should also test your code on a bundled theme to eliminate your theme as a possible culprit